# How to change my method to a generic method?

Tags: java, generics

Now I write a common way to get the JSONObject data from a key.How to change it to  a generic method?Now I have to change the type every time when I call the method.

```
String a= (String) ObdDeviceTool.getResultData(result, "a", String.class);
Double b= (Double) ObdDeviceTool.getResultData(result, "b", Double.class);
public static Object getJSONObjectData(JSONObject result,String key,Object type){ 
    if (result.containsKey(key)) { 
        if(type.equals(String.class))
            return  result.getString(key);
        if(type.equals(Double.class))
            return  result.getDouble(key);
        if(type.equals(Long.class))
            return  result.getLong(key);
        if(type.equals(Integer.class))
            return  result.getInt(key);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @JonnyHenly,I have try,but find it can not change.public static <T> T getJSONObjectData(JSONObject result,String key,T type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static <T> T getJSONObjectData(JSONObject result, String key, Class<T> type)
{
    Object value = result.get(key);
    return type.cast(value);
}
```

What you must be aware of:

- A `JSONException` will bubble up if `key` doesn't exist in `result`
- A `ClassCastException` will bubble up if `type` doesn't match the real type of `value`

Feel free to handle these a level above *if necessary*.

Comment: It has a bug, if the key value is0,result.getDouble(key) is OK.But Double.cast(0)  is wrong.

Comment: @flower Hum you are right. However I'm not sure what the best approach would be to solve that. Is it acceptable for you to retrieve the value as a `Number` ? Otherwise with this solution you'll have to pay attention to insert `0.0` when you know that you will retrieve this value as a double.

Comment: Yes,if it return 0 but sometimes return double value,I can not use your way.So I use my old way in the question demo.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the answer by @Spotted a bit further, I'd use the strategy pattern and do something like this:

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, BiFunction<JSONObject, String, Object>> converterMap =
  initializeMap();

private static Map<Class<?>, BiFunction<JSONObject, String, Object>> initializeMap() {
  Map<Class<?>, BiFunction<JSONObject,String, Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put(String.class, (jsonObject, key) -> jsonObject.getString(key));
  map.put(Integer.class, (jsonObject, key) -> jsonObject.getInt(key));
  // etc.
  return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}

private static <T> Optional<T> getJSONObjectData(JSONObject json, String key, Class<T> type) {

  return
    Optional.ofNullable(converterMap.get(key))
    .map(bifi -> bifi.apply(json, key))
    .map(type::cast);
}
```

Now you have a map of converters, where the key is the target type. If a converter exists for your type, it is used, and your object is returned in the correct type. Otherwise, Optional.empty() is returned.

This is an application of
[Effective Java (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) Item 29:
[Consider typesafe heterogeneous containers](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA142).

Comment: I like this answer for the safe casting but it doesn't compile. You should replace `Map<..., Function<...>>` with `Map<..., BiFunction<...>>` and `converterMap.get(key)` with `converterMap.get(type)`.

Comment: @Spotted ah yes, refactored from an earlier version and missed one place. thanks

Answer (score 1):

JSONObject has a method that returns an object.

```
Integer i = (Integer) result.get("integerKey");
String s = (String) result.get("stringKey");
Double d = (Double) result.get("doubleKey");
```

`result` is your JSONObject object.